# Is there a reliable way to detect if browser enable javascript in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I am trying to detect if client browser suppport javascript using asp.net/C# code. After searching online, I found two methods:

1. `bool enjs=Request.Browser.JavaScript`
2. `int version=Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion.Major` (it says if version grater and  equal to 1, the browser support javascript)

However, after testing, I found neither of them works. No matter I turned off or turned on javascript the enjs always be true, and version always equal to

Does anyone know a method could detect if browser supports javascript? I want the asp.net/c# code. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, they mention in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332781(v=vs.71).aspx) that it merely reports if the Browser is capable, not necessarily if it's currently turned on or not :-/

Comment: OK, then how to detect if the script is turned on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript to change the value of hidden form field in the page's onload event.  If the new value shows up on postbacks, you have javascript.

Comment: Note that the form field can be hijacked, so this technique has its limitations.

Comment: The problem with this is that you don't know if javascript is enabled on the first load.

Comment: I agree with Jose Valente. You still can not detect the changed hidden field value if happened on Page_Load event.

Comment: All you ever know on the first load is what was sent in the initial request.

Comment: So, there is no way to detect on the first load?

Comment: @Steven There's no way to know on the C# side. The best you can do there is a big <noscript> tag.